Google-Chrome GPO Bookmarks directly to the Bookmarks-Toolbar
I'm looking for a group policy setting on a Windows Server to deploy bookmarks directly to the clients Chrome toolbar through GPO. I've found the way to put it into the "Managed Bookmarks" folder, but I like to have them on the toolbar and not in the folder.
Any ideas?
